# Is Microsoft Translator Text API language detection performed on sentence level?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I have a question on the language detection part of Microsoft Translator Text API.

This article https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128361-api-translator-text-how-microsoft-translator-co states that:

> Translate() and TranslateArray() offer automatic detection if you omit the From language parameter. TranslateArray() returns to you the language Translator detected and used in the translation.

Is this language detection done on a sentence level or on the full text?

For instance, I have a text with mixed languages:

- the first two sentences are in Norwegian
- the two last sentences are in English

My target language is English and I omit the ***From*** language parameter.

Will the service only translate the Norwegian sentences and ignore the English ones? Or will it perform language detection on the full text, which results in either Norwegian (translate full text) or English (ignore full text).

Comment: Have you tried ? this is something like you need to test it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Detect function considers the entire input and will return the single language it has determined with the highest confidence. What you are looking for is "run detection": labeling consecutive runs of words by their language. The Translator API does not provide that.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, you may want to consider first sentence-breaking the text using the **BreakSentences** API, then detecting/processing the sentences separately.